# Parameters position in methods - params VS CancellationToken

Tags: c#

`params` should be the last parameter of a method => if violation, Compiler Error:
[CS0231] A params parameter must be the last parameter in a formal parameter list

`CancellationToken` should be the last parameter of a method => if violation, Warning CA1068: CancellationToken parameters must come last (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fundamentals/code-analysis/quality-rules/ca1068).

When we have both, we have to privilege fixing the compiling error - put the CancellationToken before `params`. If we have other parameters, the most ideal one, IMO, should be:

```
TReturnType MyMethod(int num, string str, CancellationToken ct, params MyEnum[] myEnums);
```

Is this the correct way?

Comment: I never had any issue placing CancellationToken parameter not as the last one (unlike params)

Comment: if you say "issue" by meaning compiler error, no we won't have any issue.
My question is more a coding style one.

Answer (score 3):

The cancellation token parameter must come before the `params` parameter or you can't compile. There's no way around that.

That said, there is a better way. Avoid `params` in the first place. I see a few ways of doing this.

**Multiple Overloads**

Often you will see multiple overloads for a method instead of using `params`. This is usually for performance reasons, but in your case it can be to avoid the warnings and errors.

This means you'd have to come up with a reasonable number in advance, and a final overload that takes in an array or an `IEnumerable<>`.

```
TReturnType MyMethod(int num, string str, MyEnum first, CancellationToken ct);
TReturnType MyMethod(int num, string str, MyEnum first, MyEnum second, CancellationToken ct);
TReturnType MyMethod(int num, string str, MyEnum first, MyEnum second, MyEnum third, CancellationToken ct);

TReturnType MyMethod(int num, string str, MyEnum[] myEnums, CancellationToken ct);
// and/or
TReturnType MyMethod(int num, string str, IEnumerable<MyEnum> myEnums, CancellationToken ct);
```

**Flags**

If your type happens to be an `enum` consider making it `Flags`.

```
[Flags]
public enum MyEnum
{
    Red = 1, Green = 2, Blue = 4
};
```

Then you can change the signature of the method to

```
TReturnType MyMethod(int num, string str, MyEnum myEnums, CancellationToken ct);
```

and access individual flags of `myEnums` using [HasFlag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.enum.hasflag?view=net-5.0).

Comment: thank you for your reply @Kit, Enum is just an example. It can be `params TWhateverType[]`

Comment: @yi.han cool. I made the overloads option first, as that is probably more likely to be the way to do it...